# GLib Hash Table not returning correct value

Tags: c, struct, malloc, glib

I added several key, value pairs to my GLib hash table, which is under my memory struct.  The key is a (char *) pointer returned from a malloc.  The value is the size malloc allocated.

```
void addstomemstruct(struct memory *mem, char *key_address, size_t sz) {
    g_hash_table_insert(mem->singleton, key_address, &sz);
    printf("** retrieving size: %Zu add=%p\n",(*(size_t*) g_hash_table_lookup(mem->singleton, key_address)), key_address);
}
```

Later on, when I went to retrieve the value based on the value based on the key, the returned size (value) is always 10, which was the last value I added to the hash table

```
size_t get_blocksize(GHashTable *hashtable, char *key_address, size_t *result_flag)
{   size_t *sz_ptr = (size_t *) g_hash_table_lookup(hashtable, key_address);
    ...

char *logmsg;asprintf(&logmsg,"In get_blocksize: *sz_ptr=%Zu\n",*sz_ptr);
    log_msg(logmsg);

printf("** retrieving size: %Zu add=%p\n",(*(size_t*) g_hash_table_lookup(hashtable, key_address)), key_address);
...
}
```

Printout:

```
preparing to add pointer: 0x9b52f10
** adding size: 1
** retrieving size: 1 add=0x9b52f10
preparing to add pointer: 0x9b52f48
** adding size: 2
** retrieving size: 2 add=0x9b52f48
preparing to add pointer: 0x9b52f58
** adding size: 3
...
preparing to add pointer: 0x9b52fc8
** adding size: 10
** retrieving size: 10 add=0x9b52fc8
```

then later when I try to retrieve the first value:

```
In get_blocksize: *sz_ptr=10
** retrieving size: 10 add=0x9b52f10
Freed address 0x9b52f10.  Size: 10. mem->stats->active_count=9, mem->stats->active_size=45.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to an automatic storage duration variable (function parameter) as a hash table value. When it goes outside of the scope, it's an undefined behavior to access it.

You can either:

- Allocate storage for `sz` with `malloc`/`gnew` and register an appropriate `value_destroy_func` at hash table creation.
- Take advantage of the fact that `size_t` value fits in a pointer and cast it to `gpointer`. Technically this an UB, but should work on most platforms. Probably should not do this unless small object allocation is identified as a bottleneck.

Comment: thanks. What do you mean by UB? Does the second option allow me not to have to allocate space? The hash table exists outside of the scope of the function that calls get_blocksize.

Comment: UB = undefined behavior. Yes, you cast the value to pointer at store and back at retrieval. Just don't use it as a pointer (GLib doesn't internally).

Comment: You can use the macros `GSIZE_TO_POINTER` and `GPOINTER_TO_SIZE` which accomplish that conversion in a platform-independent way.